# It is right my auth in codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
    if($this->session->userdata('admin') === false)
    {
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $data['content'] = $this->load->view(ADMIN.'login', null, true);
        $this->load->view(ADMIN.'layout', $data);

        return false;
    }
```

so this is the code in the controller admin, function constructor.

It checks if the admin session is true, the question is how bad is this type of authorization, by checking it in the constructor? Because the user can't use other functions in this controller before he didn't pass the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
Class AdminPanel extends CI_Controller{
  function __construct(){
    if($this->session->userdata('admin') === false)
      redirect(site_url());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a library, and do all checking like this inside. After loading this library into your Controller, then you can use your - for example `isAdmin();` - function in any part of your Controller's code.